# How facades work in laravel? How the methods can be accessed with ::

Tags: php, facade, laravel-facade

I read about Facade Pattern

> The facade pattern (also spelled façade) is a software design pattern commonly used with object-oriented programming. The name is an analogy to an architectural façade. A facade is an object that provides a simplified interface to a larger body of code, such as a class library.

But in Laravel all the Facade Classes methods are accessed via the **`::`(Scope Resolution Operator)** even though the methods are not static at all.

How is this possible? Why PHP is not telling that the method is not static.

for example `Auth::user()` eventhough the `user()` method is [not static](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php) how is is accessible, somewhere the class should be newed up or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The magic happens in `Facade`'s [`__callStatic`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php#L213) function.

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
{
    $instance = static::getFacadeRoot();
    if (! $instance) {
        throw new RuntimeException('A facade root has not been set.');
    }
    return $instance->$method(...$args);
}
```

It first gets the appropriate instance, and then simply invokes the requested method with the given arguments.

Comment: where do the instances are stored then?

Comment: @ShobiPP Please check the source I have linked. `Facade` is an abstract class that is implemented by types like `Auth` and `DB`. Those can all be found in `Illuminate\Support\Facades`: https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/5.6/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades